# How to properly look for a string in a file?

Tags: c, string, fgets

In this function, I am displaying a .txt document to the screen, which works, however, I am trying to read the file document and scan the document for the word EMPTY as I have it saved as a string variable. It should be noted that I am counting the time EMPTY is in the file and later printing the times it was would in the file along with on another thing. My first question is am I doing this correct?

```
 void allSeats(void)
    {
        int position = 0;
        int count = 0;
        char gone[6] = "EMPTY";

        system("cls");
    retry: 
        fseatArrangement = fopen("airlineSeatingArrangment.txt", "r");
        while (fgets(econoAirSeatArrangement, 1000, fseatArrangement) != NULL)
            printf(econoAirSeatArrangement);
        fclose(fseatArrangement);

        while (count < FULL)
        {
            fgets(econoAirSeatArrangement, 1000, fseatArrangement);
            fscanf(fseatArrangement,"%s", &gone);
            count++;
        }
        printf("There are %d seats vacant at the moment\nThere are %d seats with no vacancy at the moment \n",count, FULL-count);


        printf("Enter Zero(0) Key to return to menu at anytime.");
            scanf("%d", &position);
            if (position == 0)
            {
                system("cls");
                menu();
            }
            else
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("INVALID INPUT! Please try again.\n");
                goto retry;
            }

        system("pause");
        return;

    }
```

Comment: what is `sting`?

Comment: `printf(econoAirSeatArrangement);`...smelling fishy...

Comment: why? @Sourav Ghosh

Comment: Invitation for malicious or accidental damage. Use `puts` or `printf("%s", econoAirSeatArrangement)`

Comment: There are places and situations where labels and `goto` are okay. Instead of loops is not one of those places.

Comment: We are not a free code-verification service. Read [ask] and follow the advice!

Comment: @Olaf why did you remove my last comment

Comment: @eM3e: I did not remove it. Maybe you should refrain from adding snarky/non-constructive comments and instead follow site-rules.

Comment: @Olaf how would you know its snarky/non-constructive if you didn't delete it, it would have been gone? Now before you tell me to gtfo, or not to ask you any question because your not my free code verification service, do you have a suggestion towards the program I am writing for the record I  have researched my problem and I can't find anything as well I have had friends look at my code?

Comment: "how would you know its snarky/non-constructive if you didn't delete it" - non sequitur! Could I possibly have read it before it was deleted? You really should take the [tour] and read the FAQ. For further discussion, please notice comments are not for this. If you have a general question, ask on meta.

Comment: Using `goto retry` strongly suggests you aren't handling it in the best way.

Comment: @Olaf to be fair I never said It wasn't snarky, you just assumed that as I assumed your ability to help out other programmers if you wanted me to go somewhere else, next time ask.

Comment: @jonathan leffler what are you suggesting?

Comment: You shouldn't use `goto retry;` — you should use an appropriate loop, probably a `while` loop, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is here

```
 fgets(econoAirSeatArrangement, 1000, fseatArrangement);
```

you have already closed the file pointer using `fclose()`, and yet, you try to use it. It  causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said,

- `printf(econoAirSeatArrangement);` appears wrong. If you do not wish to have any format conversion specification you can stick to `puts()`.
- You must check the return value of `fopen()`, `fgets()`, `fscanf()` etc. for success before using the returned value / scanned value.

Comment: can you expand? I removed that and placed it after where i needed to close it but nothing still

Comment: i changed the code a bit and am now using freads i do know if that makes it any better but i am still getting nothing?

Comment: @eM3e Do not change the code in the question, it makes the answer invalid. Also, did you apply all the changes I suggested in my answer?

Comment: The OP tried leaving the file open, but is already at EOF so there is nothing to read. Close and re-open, or call `rewind`. And `fread` is not the usual way to read a text file.

Comment: yes i changed moved the fclose added %s in the printf statement and the use fopen fgets and fscanf i dont know what you mean by that sorry no to code inclinded

Comment: @ Weather Vane i closed and re opened the file and nothign

Comment: Very strange to be using `fgets` **and** `fscanf`. In fact `fscanf(fseatArrangement,"%s", &gone);` is bizarre. Think of using `strstr`.

Comment: @ Weather Vane ill be honest i have little to no clue what i am doing for this i am just tryng to see how many times the word empty is in the file

Comment: @ Weather Vane worked perfectly i just did realize what i did wrong thats alot man